# Determinant and Inverse of a Difference of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've got an expression of the form 
\begin{equation}\det(I-AB)\end{equation} and I'm wondering if there is a way to write this solely in terms of functions of $A$ and $B$. For the particular case I'm considering, $A$ is some diagonal matrix and $B$ is some symmetric matrix with zeroes on the diagonal, so I would think since the matrix $I-AB$ only differs by some diagonal elements and a few other things it would be possible to construct this determinant from $A$ and $B$ in general. Also the inverse of such a matrix, i.e. $(I-AB)^{-1}$ would be useful to know as well. In general, $||AB||>1$ so I don't think I can expand the inverse in powers of $AB$ the usual way. 
Anyways, thanks for any help.

Comment: You can check this article. It uses some technics to perform such calculations : 
http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/

Comment: $$\left(\mathbf{I}_p + \mathbf{UV}\right)^{-1} = \mathbf{I}_p - \mathbf{U}\left(\mathbf{I}_q + \mathbf{VU}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{V}.$$

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "$I - AB$ only differs by some diagonal elements and a few other things". Anyway, you know $\det(I - AB) = \det(I - BA)$ and if $A$ is invertible, $\det(I - AB) = \det(A^{-1} - B)$. I don't know if this helps though. Regarding the inverse, I do not know of anything particularly applicable to this specific problem, but if you have more knowledge of $A$ and $B$, maybe the Woodbury identity or the binomial inverse theorem could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The product $A \cdot B$ is a symmetric matrix again. If I summarize your question: Given a symmetric matrix $B$ with zeros on the diagonal, is there a simple way to compute $\det(I - B)$.

Answer: There is none in general. A good approximation for a $B$ with only small entries is
$$\det(I - B) = 1 - {\rm trace} (B).$$

However, consider that $I - B$ has only $1$'s on the diagonal. Thus, it should be relatively easy to reduce the problem to lower dimensions.